# Cursor waits in the wrong window

Tags: c, sockets, cursor, client, ncurses

I am developing a simple chat. The chat client is based on ncurses, and has two window:

- The "input" window, where users enter messages.
- The "output" window, where users see messages by other users.

My client has two threads, one for getting messages from the user, and one for displaying messages from the server.

When users type messages, they appear as expected in the input window.

[image: Cursor in input window]

The problem is that once a message is sent, the cursor just waits in the output window till a key is pressed.

[image: Cursor in output window]

This is rather annoying (it also happens when the client loses focus). How can I force the cursor to be in a certain window?

The relevant code is here:

```
WINDOW* in;
WINDOW* out;
...
void chatter(int sockfd)
{
    ...
    pthread_create(&sendt, NULL, sender, &sockfd);

    while (1)
    {
        bytes = recv(sockfd, msg, sizeof msg - 1, 0);

        if (bytes != 0)
        {
            if (bytes == -1)
            {
                wprintw(out, "Error receiving message: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            }
            else
            {
                msg[bytes] = '\0';
                wprintw(out, "%s", msg);
            }

            wrefresh(out);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_cancel(sendt);
    pthread_detach(sendt);
    ...
}

void* sender(void* pfd)
{
    char msg[MAX_MSG] = "";
    int sockfd = *(int *)pfd;

    while (1)
    {
        mvwgetnstr(in, 0, 0, msg, sizeof msg - 2);
        strcat(msg, "\n");

        if (send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg) + 1, 0) == -1)
        {
            wprintw(out, "Error sending message: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        werase(in);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling wmove() and wrefresh() before the call to mvwgetnstr()?

Comment: @Craig Yes, it doesn't work. It also seems to cause weird character glitches. I guess it has to do with the fact that reads and writes happen in the same time.

Comment: ncurses is not thread safe.  Create a single thread that does all of the ncurses work or make sure you have locks around the ncurses calls.